# unable to use friend class' method

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code. I have two classes, Run and Robot, and I want an object of type Robot to change a private member of an object of type Run. To be specific, I want to increment the value of 'x' in the following code.

The following errors pop up:

error: 'getX' was not declared in this scope
error: 'getX' was not declared in this scope

I have pinpointed with an arrow (<---) the line where the error occurs. The following code is just a test, just to learn how to use the 'friend' keyword for a project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Robot;

class Run{
    friend class Robot;
private:
    int x;
    vector<Robot*>robots;
public:
    Run();
    vector<Robot*>*getRobots();
    void createRobot();
    void movAll();
    void setX(int);
    int getX();
};

class Robot{
    friend class Run;
public:
    Robot();
    void movingRobot();
};

Run::Run(){}

vector<Robot*>*Run::getRobots(){return &robots;}
void Run::createRobot(){getRobots()->push_back(new Robot);setX(1);}
void Run::movAll(){getRobots()->at(0)->movingRobot();}
int Run::getX(){return x;}
void Run::setX(int c){x=c;}

Robot::Robot(){}

void Robot::movingRobot(){setX(getX()+1);}    <-------------------------

int main(){
    Run Sim;
    Sim.createRobot();
    Sim.movAll();
}
```

Using the 'friend' keyword will definitely help on my project, so I am trying to understand how to use it.

Comment: I don't see the arrow.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Just edited.

Comment: Your design is wrong, you should use inheritance and virtual methods Why exposing unnecessarily private members  ?

Comment: using inheritance would be a nicer way to go, however if using friend functions is a requirement for the project let me know, and I will try and provide information for you in either case

Comment: Yes, using 'friend' keyword is required.

Comment: The way I see the code is that the run class is intended to contain a vector of all the robots you need, and then you want to be able to move all the robots by issuing a `run.moveAll()` i take it?  Let me know if I have this right as I think there is an easy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: also are the robots to exist as seperate entities that can be accessed from the vector in run or are they to exist entirely inside the vector in run?

Comment: posted some code below for you to peruse.  Let me know if you need more info:)

Answer (score 1):

You're just calling `getX()` and `setX()` as if they're methods of Robot. You need to call the function against an instance of `Run`, and in this case you don't need it to be a friend because getX() is public anyway.

That said, do you want each Robot to have an `x` value that you want to increment? In that case, you need it to be a member of Robot rather than Run.

If you want `Run` to have a single value of `x` that all instances of Robot can access and modify, then just make `x` static, then access it directly rather than calling the public methods, which don't require another class to be a friend anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is how I want to do it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: To specifically answer your question, you need an object of type `Run` to begin with. I'm not exactly sure that's what you want to do though. It looks like x should be a member of Robot.

Comment: I understand this. But I have to call the function movingRobot() from class Robot and change the value of the private member of Run. That's how getX() gets in the way.

Comment: `getX()` and `set()` are both members of `Robot`, so you need a Robot object on which to call the method, like `Robot r; r.getX()`.

Comment: The problem is that I have class Run with vectors from another 3 classes and the member functions of Run change the corresponding 'x', which is a vector for with 400 objects, each one of them is block of 20x20 Map. Yet I have to use a moving function for the Robots on the Map, which should be a member function of class Robot.

Comment: Robot isn't holding any data you see, at present it really doesn't make any sense. The Robot class doesn't have any reference to a Rule object, neither as a class member or locally, so calling `setX()` or `getX()` currently makes no sense.

Comment: Is there no way for an object of type Robot, like that in the vector, to have access the private members of another class, like Run? Just the way it is?

Comment: Yes, but it's got to have a `Run` object to call the method against. You don't have that, you need a pointer to a `Run` object at the very least. Although I'm not entirely certain what `x` is meant to represent.

Comment: X is supposed to be the coordinates on 2D array. But instead of the 2D array, I am using a vector. The reason is that I have multiple data for each block of the array, and a vector is better suited. Now, there are robots on the Map, which are supposed to move and do some other stuff, for which we do not care yet. First, I am concerned how to move the robots. And as you can see above, there is the class Robot for the Robots, and there is another class (I am calling it PlanetBlocks) for the Map, and finally all interact inside the class Run, where everything takes place.

Comment: The problem is that I have to use a moving function for the Robots, which is supposed to be a member function of the Robot class.

Comment: If I could make the robots of class Robot to have access to the vector of PlanetBlocks, then I am done, I know exactly what I have to do. But I do not know any other way to do this except using the 'friend' keyword. Some friens of mine suggested using pointers, but I am not familiar with pointers, so I am trying anything else I can in order to avoid them. Among all the methods I could come up, 'friend' seems to be one valid way.

Answer (score 0):

You called `getX` as if it were a function of the Robot-class. You need a run object to call it:

```
run.getX()
```

Comment: There is my problem. I want in my main( ) to create an object of type Run, and everything must work like the pattern in my code. Is there any way to call it without creating an object of type Run?

Comment: This function is declared as a non-static method, therefore you need a Run-object. If it doesn't access any instance-members, you can declare it as static and access it with `Run::getX()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can remove the `getX()` function from The `Robot` class as it has no code body at present anyway, and for internal use the robot class can always utilise its X variable.  `Run` doesn't need to have a `friend class Robot`, as Robot should not need to look into `Run` for anything, and as `Run` contains a vector of  pointers to instances of `Robot` it can access any values of `Robot` instances by looking at the contents of its vector (for example `myRunInstance.getRobots()[1]->getX()` would return the x value of the 2nd robot in the vector of robots).

Now the `getX` function will have to vary a tad if it is to remain in the `Run` class: you will need to specify a way to make it gather the information of a specific instance of the `Robot` class, presumably from its vector of Robots.  I have respecced your code above and added a small proof of concept set of code to the main, makes 10 robots moves them all using moveall, then sets Johnny5 to a special place (because he IS special:)  Something along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Run;


class Robot{
    friend class Run;   // allows the Run class to access all the private data as if it were its own
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Robot() {};
        void setX(int newX) {   x= newX;    }
        int getX()          {   return x;   }
        void movingRobot()  {   x+=1;   }

};

class Run{
private:
    vector<Robot*> robots;
public:
    Run(){};
    vector<Robot*> *getRobots() {   return &robots; }
    void createRobot()          {   robots.push_back(new Robot()); robots.back()->x =1; }
    void movAll()               {   for (int i=0;i<robots.size();i++){ robots[i]->movingRobot();}   }
    int getX(int robotPosition){    return robots[robotPosition]->x;    }  //uses the friend status to read directly from Robot class instances x
    void setX(int rpos, int xval){  robots[rpos]->setX(xval);   }
};


int main()
{
    Run *Sim = new Run();
    for (int i =0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            Sim->createRobot();
            Sim->setX(i,i); // uses the Run setX
            std::cout << "Robot " << i << "(starting position): " << Sim->getRobots()->at(i)->getX() << std::endl;
        }
    Sim->movAll();
    // lets move Johnny 5 to 55 as well...
   (Sim->getRobots()->at(4))->setX(55); // uses the robot setx
    for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Robot " << i << "(final position): " << Sim->getRobots()->at(i)->getX()<< std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Source also viewable with sample output at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9rEDvU)